# Background image doesn't show on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, tablet

My background image just works fine in the browser but when I open the site on my mobile or tablet the background image (set on body) doesn't show and it just shows a blank white background.

This is the code im using to set my background:

```
body {
  background:url('../img/bg.jpg') top fixed no-repeat;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why my image doesn't work on mobile devices?

Thanks!

Comment: Give us more code...

Comment: As others have mentioned you should give us a a littlebit more info. For example provide a test case at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net). Just out of curiosity I did [test case](https://jsfiddle.net/9v607jvv/1/embedded/result/) for background property on an android 2.3.3 browser and it displayed correctly.